# Можно ли как-то установить или использовать Baseflight Configurator?

Tags: c++, c, микроконтроллеры, робототехника

У меня есть "самодельный" полётный контроллер на базе stm32f103, на нем зашита прошивка от Baseflight.
В состав полётного контроллера входит(МК, Акселерометр и Гироскоп, барометр).Хотелось бы проверить работает вообще эта штука. С 22 года Google Chrome начали закрывать Приложения Chrome. Только оттуда можно было установить и использовать Baseflight configurator.
Есть способы решения этой проблемы?
Как обойти это? Проверить работу.

Comment: https://github.com/multiwii/baseflight-configurator Пробовали?

Comment: Пробовал,не работает (

Answer (score 0):

1. Качаем старую версию **Google Chrome**, предварительно удалив актуальную версию с компьютера. Я скачивал [отсюда](https://google-chrome.ru.uptodown.com/windows/download/2196902).
2. Ставим **baseflight-configurator** через магазин расширений или качаем с [github](https://github.com/multiwii/baseflight-configurator) и ставим вручную. Для второго способа *настройки->расширения->режим разработчика->загрузить распакованное расширение*.
3. Убираем автообновление **Google Chrome**. По пути `C:\Program Files (x86)\Google` находим папку `Update` и меняем её название на любое, какое захочется. Это не даст браузеру обновиться на последнюю версию.